# Ominifaces EL String passing

Tags: java, jsf, facelets, omnifaces

OminiFaces's 'o:methodParam' does now work for me as below. How can I use another way? I don't know what I am missing in it. It can work with `<h:commandButton>` and `<a4j:jsFunction>` without using `Seam` , When `Seam` is used it does not work with `<a4j:jsFunction>`.

Development Eviroment is 
        `RichFaces 4.
         Seam 2.3
         OminiFaces 1.2 JBoss 7.1.1`

```
@Name("DataTableBacking")
public class DataTableBacking {

    Department[] items = {new Department("AAA", "AAA"), new Department("BBB", "BBB"), new Department("CCC", "CCC")};

    public Department[] getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void action(Department action) {
        System.out.println("Action called with:" + action.getName());
    }

}
```

datatable.xhtml

```
<h:html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:richm="http://developmentTutorials.com/java">
        <h:body>
            <h:form>
            <h1>Data Table</h1>
                <rich:dataTable id="departmentTable" value="#{DataTableBacking.items}" var="dep" style="width:100%">
                    <rich:column style="width:100px;text-align:center;">
                        #{dep.name}
                        <richm:confirmLink actionBeanMethod="#{DataTableBacking.action(dep)}" render="departmentTable"/>
                    </rich:column>
                </rich:dataTable>
            </h:form>
        </h:body>
</h:html>
```

In tag lib, confirmation.xml

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j" 
    xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:of="http://omnifaces.org/functions"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <o:methodParam name="methodParam" value="#{actionBeanMethod}" />

    <a4j:commandLink value="delete" onclick="#{rich:component('confirmation')}.show();return false" />

    <h:commandButton value="direct" action="#{methodParam}" />

    <a4j:jsFunction name="submit" action="#{methodParam}" render="#{render}" />

    <rich:popupPanel id="confirmation" width="250" height="150">
        <f:facet name="header">Confirmation</f:facet>
        <h:panelGrid>

            <h:panelGrid columns="1">
                <h:outputText value="Are you sure?" style="FONT-SIZE: large;" />
            </h:panelGrid>

            <h:panelGroup>
                <input type="button" value="OK" onclick="#{rich:component('confirmation')}.hide(); submit(); return false" />
                <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="#{rich:component('confirmation')}.hide(); return false" />
            </h:panelGroup>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </rich:popupPanel>

</ui:composition>
```

Comment: To confirm, is the `#{ManageDepartmentAction}` in view scope and is the `getDepartmentList()` a pure getter?

Comment: `ManageDepartmentAction` is JBoss Seam's `Conversation` scope. `getDepartmentList()` is a pure getter method. The `departmentList` already retrieve from DB at bean initial state`(By using @Begin)`. `getDepartmentList()` method just return `departmentList`.

Comment: What happens if you change "@Named" ("@Name is typo?) into the @ManagedBean from JSF? Watch out that there are two of those annotations, in this case you need the javax.faces one.

Comment: And what happens if you add @RequestScoped to @Named? (now you need the **non** javax.faces one). CDI beans are by default in the depent scope. I don't see the conversation scope being used in your code.

Comment: It will be `conversation Scope`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure about the `null` value. If data would be absent after the post-back (an often recurring mistake) the method should not be called at all.

You do have a bug in your code though, and that's that `a4j:jsFunction` will create a function and assign it to a js variable named `submit`, and this will be the same for every row.

So `submit=function(){RichFaces.ajax("j_idt15:departmentTable:0:j_idt18" ...` for the first row, `submit=function(){RichFaces.ajax("j_idt15:departmentTable:1:j_idt18" ...` for the second row, and so on.

Your dialog will then always call the one from the last row. So, possible, is there a `null` as the last value in the list that you feed the table?

Using the following slightly simplified code, I get the passed parameter in the action method:

```
@ManagedBean
public class DataTableBacking {

    String[] items = {"A", "B"};

    public String[] getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void action(String action) {
        System.out.println("Action called with:" + action);
    }

}
```

datatable.xhtml:

```xml
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:richm="http://developmentTutorials.com/java"
>
    <h:head/>
    <h:body>

        <h:form>
            <rich:dataTable id="departmentTable" value="#{dataTableBacking.items}" var="dep" style="width:100%">
                <rich:column style="width:100px;text-align:center;">
                    #{dep}
                    <richm:confirmLink actionBeanMethod="#{dataTableBacking.action(dep)}" render="departmentTable"/>
                </rich:column>
            </rich:dataTable>
        </h:form>

    </h:body>
</html>
```

confirmation.xhtml:

```xml
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j" 
    xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:of="http://omnifaces.org/functions"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <o:methodParam name="methodParam" value="#{actionBeanMethod}" />

    <a4j:commandLink value="delete" onclick="#{rich:component('confirmation')}.show();return false" />

    <h:commandButton value="direct" action="#{methodParam}" />

    <a4j:jsFunction name="submit" action="#{methodParam}" render="#{render}" />

    <rich:popupPanel id="confirmation" width="250" height="150">
        <f:facet name="header">Confirmation</f:facet>
        <h:panelGrid>

            <h:panelGrid columns="1">
                <h:outputText value="Are you sure?" style="FONT-SIZE: large;" />
            </h:panelGrid>

            <h:panelGroup>
                <input type="button" value="OK" onclick="#{rich:component('confirmation')}.hide(); submit(); return false" />
                <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="#{rich:component('confirmation')}.hide(); return false" />
            </h:panelGroup>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </rich:popupPanel>

</ui:composition>
```

I added the direct call via a `h:commandButton` to validate that the expression does make it correctly to the Facelet tag. In this example, when I click the `delete` link and confirm, I get the last element (B) as expected in the `action()` method for both rows.

I used JBoss AS 7.1.1, OmniFaces 1.2 Snapshot and RichFaces 4.0.0. The OmniFaces version shouldn't matter too much as I didn't make any changes to the `methodParam` between those versions (I'm the author of that particular part).

Which server and with which versions of OmniFaces and RichFaces are you using?

***Edit***

Per the comments, changing the `String` into a `Department`:

DataTableBacking.java:

```
@ManagedBean
public class DataTableBacking {

    Department[] items = {new Department(), new Department()};

    public Department[] getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void action(Department action) {
        System.out.println("Action called with:" + action);
    }

}
```

Department.java:

```
public class Department {

}
```

(all the other code the same as before)

This should and (at my side) indeed does not make any difference. When you changed the `String` array into a `Department` one, did you do it in the same way as I did? Can you show your full backing bean?

Comment: My development environment is ; `OminiFaes 1.1, JBoss AS 7.1.1, Richfaces 4.0.0., Seam 2.3, Spring 3.0, JPA 2.0`.

Comment: I test as you suggest. I also used Ominiface 1.2 versin.

  `<h:commandButton value="direct" action="#{methodParam}" />
  <a4j:jsFunction name="submit" action="#{methodParam}" render="#{render}" />`

These two action method get the same value `NULL`.

Comment: Have you also tested Arjan's code example or even compared it to your actual code to see if the technical design differs in some way which could possibly be the cause of the problem?

Comment: When I test Arjan's code, it is perfectly work well for `Sting Array datatable`. When I replace with `String Array` with `Department Object Array` and also delete method accept `Department parameter`, `<h:commandButton>` work well. But `<a4j:jsFunction>` does not work.

Comment: @CycDemo if I quickly change the code use a (dummy) `Department`, I still get an instance in the action method. See updated answer.

Comment: Thz, I am wasting your time. I think, the problem of `Seam`. I also update the my question.

Answer (score 0):

I try to fix this problem with `javascript`. It can be unsuitable solution. The `datatable` pass `row Index` as parameter because of I would like to get id of `<h:commandButton>` for each row of datatable. JavaScript will click the `<h:commandButton>` when the user click `OK` button in ConfirmationBox.

confirmation.xml

```
    <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j" 
    xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:of="http://omnifaces.org/functions"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <o:methodParam name="methodParam" value="#{actionBeanMethod}" />
    <a4j:commandLink value="#{value}" onclick="#{rich:component('confirmation')}.show();return false"/>

    <h:commandButton id="commandButton" value="direct" action="#{methodParam}" style="display:none;"/>

    <rich:popupPanel id="confirmation" width="250" height="150">
        <f:facet name="header">Confirmation</f:facet>
        <h:panelGrid>

            <h:panelGrid columns="1">
                <h:outputText value="Are you sure ?" style="FONT-SIZE: large;" />
            </h:panelGrid>

            <h:panelGroup>
                <input type="button" value="OK" onclick="document.getElementById('#{index}:commandButton').click();#{rich:component('confirmation')}.hide();return false;" />
                <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="#{rich:component('confirmation')}.hide(); return false" />
            </h:panelGroup>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </rich:popupPanel>

    </ui:composition>
```

In datatable;

```
    <rich:dataTable id="departmentTable" value="#{DataTableBacking.items}" var="dep" style="width:100%" rowKeyVar="index">
        <rich:column style="width:100px;text-align:center;">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Name"/>
            </f:facet>
            #{dep.name}
            <richm:confirmLink value ="Delete" index="tableForm:departmentTable:#{index}" actionBeanMethod="#{DataTableBacking.action(dep)}" render="departmentTable"/>
        </rich:column>
    </rich:dataTable>
```